# Is there a device with multiple serial ports to configure multiple devices

Tags: serial-port, splitter

Is there a device that has multiple serial ports that I can connect to my computer so that I can connect other networking devices that can be configured from the serial port to this device and then configure these devices from my PC?

Here is a diagram of what I am trying to accomplish.  I am looking for a device that I can use in the red position in the diagram.

[image: Connection Diagram]

Comment: What is the AUX port?  Are you talking about a serial port?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my question

Comment: There is this that will do serial with an RJ45 (you'd have to get DB9 to RJ45 cables for it): https://www.digi.com/products/serialservers/connectportts4x4 - It might help to know more specifically what the devices/pinouts/uses would be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for a serial terminal server or console server. Many manufacturers make them such as Raritan, Lantronix, and Black box.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bert said, one way to do this is with a Serial Terminal Server or a Console Server.

However, if you will only be using one of these devices at a time and you will be in the same physical location, you could use a much simpler physical switch box, like this one:

[image: 4-port serial switch]

These devices usually have a bunch of buttons or a dial on the front and they actually physically switch between the different connections and your computer.

It's much more old-school, but much easier and cheaper *if that's all you need*.

Comment: +1 Thanks this also a good idea, but it is not what I require.